# getAsString() jsf customed converter fails to convert object

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, converters

I created a custom converter for jsf. The getAsObject() works perfect but the getAsString() is returning an exception. I am not really sure where the problem is, and I have tried converting the object to string in different ways, but it keeps on returning exception.

This my converters code:

```
    @Named
public class ProductConverter implements Converter{

    @EJB
    private ProductEJB productEjb;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if(value== null )
        {
            throw new ConverterException("There was an error at getAsObject()");
        }

        int id = Integer.parseInt(value);
        return productEjb.findProductById(id);
    }

    @Override    
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {        

        if (value == null || value.equals("")) 
        {
            return "";            
        }
        else
        {
            Integer id = ((Product)value).getProduct_id();
            return String.valueOf(id);
        }

    }

}
```

This is the Product class (Getters/Setters/equals()/hash() excluded for simplicity):

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="findAllProducts", query = "SELECT p from Product p")

})
public class Product implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int product_id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    protected byte[] imageFile;
    private Float price;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateAdded;        
    @ManyToOne
    private Category category_fk;
    @ManyToOne
    private SaleDetails saleDetails_fk;
```

This is stack I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at com.lv.Controllers.Converters.ProductConverter.getAsObject(ProductConverter.java:30)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:171)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewParameter.getConvertedValue(UIViewParameter.java:394)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewParameter.processValidators(UIViewParameter.java:273)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This is the jsf where I am using the converter:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="product" value="#{productDelete.product}" converter="#{productConverter}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't throw an exception when `null` or an empty value is received. This makes no sense. They may represent legitimately valid values which just represent "no value". Just return `null` then. If you'd like to force requireness, then you should be using `required="true"` instead or any custom `Validator`, but just don't do that in a `Converter`.

You should throw the `ConverterException` only when the value is *really* unconvertable. I've improved your converter to do exactly that. You are namely not checking if the submitted value is a valid number nor if the obtained model value is an instance of `Product`. It would otherwise have caused `NumberFormatException` or `ClassCastException` further down in the code which you should have prevented beforehand by throwing the appropriate `ConverterException`.

```
@Named
public class ProductConverter implements Converter {

    @EJB
    private ProductEJB productEjb;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!value.matches("\\d+")) {
            throw new ConverterException("The value is not a valid ID number: " + value);
        }

        int id = Integer.parseInt(value);
        return productEjb.findProductById(id);
        // You may want to perform an additional check if it didn't return null
        // and otherwise throw ConverterException with "unknown Product ID".
    }

    @Override    
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {        
        if (value == null) {
            return null; // Or an empty string, can also.
        }

        if (!(value instanceof Product)) {
            throw new ConverterException("The value is not a valid Product: " + value);
        }

        Integer id = ((Product)value).getProduct_id();
        return (id != null) ? String.valueOf(id) : null;
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you very much, I have made the suggested changes to my converter and the problem has been fixed. I discovered some other errors. I got a `javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException` , `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: null is not a known entity type.` and `javax.ejb.EJBException`. I will try to resolve them on my own, if I can t I will post a new question, to avoid mixing pears and apples. Once again thank you very much, I am new JSF and thanks to you I now better understand the structure of a converter.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your method cant handle when the value is null. Try returning an empty string in that case

```
public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
        return "";
    } else {
        Integer id = ((Product)value).getProduct_id();
        return String.valueOf(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have changed my code accordingly (following your example) however, I am now getting a `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this? I have updated the stack in the original posting, as well as my converter class. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The value expression `#{productDelete.product}` is resolving to null.

*Note: the [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html#getAsString%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent,%20java.lang.Object%29) for a converter states that `getAsString` returns an empty string for null values.*

Comment: Thanks you very much. I have reviewed the method detail explanation and made adjustments to the code reflecting contract for a converter. However, I got a new stack and it now returns the empty string as part of stack. I have updated my post reflecting the new results as well as the changes to my converter class. At a point it is referring to the getAsObject(), could that the problem is in the get as object?

Comment: @lv10 - getAsObject should perform the inverse operation to getAsString; it is still throwing an exception. See BalusC's answer.