# JSF javax.faces.convert Converter getAsString Object null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, null, converters

I am working on an application and I used JSF within this application, I wrote a Java class which implements this interface JSF `javax.faces.convert`, and also overwrite the method `getAsString` of Converter, here is the Java doc of this method:

```
java.lang.String getAsString(FacesContext context,
                             UIComponent component,
                             java.lang.Object value)
```

But sometimes, the value here is `Null`, sometimes it works well,

does anybody know that why this value is null here? how to prevent it to happen?

Comment: post your converter code and JSF code

Comment: Coverter code:

public abstract class ValueConverter implements Converter {

    protected abstract Value findAsString(String s);

    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object o) {
        Value p = (Value) o;
        if(p.getId()!=null){ return p.getId().toString();}
        return(p.toString());
    }

}

Comment: i think your incoming Object o may be null sometime. for that only you get null

Comment: When will this situation happen? how this null object coming?

Comment: you only know the exact situation. If the Object value is null then you can return empty string. place the condition in your getAsString method

Answer (score 3):

It will be `null` if the model value is `null`. For example,

```
public class SomeBean {

    private SomeObject someObject;

    // Let's assume, someObject is never initialized and defaults to null.
}
```

If you use

```
<h:outputText value="#{someBean.someObject}" converter="someConverter" />
```

then the `getAsString()` will be invoked with `null` value.

Also, if you use for example,

```
<h:selectOneMenu ... converter="someConverter">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Please select ..." />
    <f:selectItems value="#{data.availableItems}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

then the `getAsString()` will be invoked with `null` value for the "Please select..." item.

If you're facing `NullPointerException`, then it's actually a bug in **your own** converter implementation. You can't prevent the supplied `value` from being `null`. Even more, the [javadoc which you apparently already found yourself](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html#getAsString%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent,%20java.lang.Object%29), also explicitly tells that the model object value may be null.

> `value` - Model object value to be converted (may be `null`)

You should just be checking on that yourself. Here's a typical example how a converter should look like for a fictive `User` entity:

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
    if (submittedValue == null || submittedValue.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        return userService.find(Long.valueOf(submittedValue));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(String.format("%s is not a valid User ID", submittedValue)), e);
    }
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) {
    if (modelValue == null) {
        return "";
    }

    if (modelValue instanceof User) {
        return String.valueOf(((User) modelValue).getId());
    } else {
        throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(String.format("%s is not a valid User", modelValue)), e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look [converter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html#getAsString%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent,%20java.lang.Object%29)

```
public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object o)
  {
    if (o == null)
      {
         return "";
      }
    Value p = (Value) o;
    if (p.getId() != null)
      {
        return p.getId().toString();
      }
    return (p.toString());
  }
```

Comment: You didn't answer the question.

Comment: he got the null value so only i did like this.

Comment: OP also asked *"does anybody know that why this value is null here?"*

Comment: i know but the object o value may be null. Here i refered your answer and then i did like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244535/getasstring-jsf-customed-converter-fails-to-convert-object

Comment: You're nowhere answering the question. You just pasted a link and posted some code without any further elaboration in own words about the cause and the solution. I did actually not look in the link.

Comment: @BalusC sorry for that. for that only i give the converter link