# What Java API replacement exists (if any) for com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TextRenderer

Tags: java, jsf, sonarqube

On a Java web project (running on Tomcat & JSF & Spring), a custom renderer was written to get custom converters to be called even if the value to be converted is `null`, as is explained here: [JSF Custom Converter not called on null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048438/jsf-custom-converter-not-called-on-null-value)

However, the SonarQube scan is detecting an issue on the `import` line, namely:

```
import com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TextRenderer;
```

as it is a `com.sun.*` package and not a standard Java API package. The rule description states:

> ## Classes from "sun.*" packages should not be used (squid:S1191)
>
> Classes in the `sun.*` or `com.sun.*` packages are considered implementation details, and are not part of the Java API.
>
> They can cause problems when moving to new versions of Java because there is no backwards compatibility guarantee. Similarly, they can cause problems when moving to a different Java vendor, such as OpenJDK.
>
> Such classes are almost always wrapped by Java API classes that should be used instead.
>
> ### Noncompliant Code Example
>
> ```
> import com.sun.jna.Native;     // Noncompliant
> import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder; // Noncompliant
> ```

This makes good sense and all, but I can't find a Java API wrapper for this class, only the source code and packages that the class is in... What is the appropriate action to take in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is kind of false positive. Usage of `com.sun.faces` is an usage of internal implementation-specific classes but for JSF rather than JDK. Those classes will not be removed by other JVMs or some new version of JDK. You just bind your code to Sun's (Oracle's) implementation of JSF which might be OK or not OK for you.

Looking into the code of that rule at [GitHub](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/SunPackagesUsedCheck.java#L42), it looks like that it is configurable to avoid such false positives but setting the `exclude` property as a comma-separated list. I am not sure where exactly you can do this in UI but https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE50/Configuring+Rules might be a starting point.

Comment: @BalusC, I'm not sure I agree with you. Title and description of the warning don't really match. The title says that using `com.sun.*` is binding to some implemetnation details (but not to Oracle's JDK's details) and that you should try to use some `java.*` or `javax.*` classes instead which **is** true. Description is currently mostly focused on `sun.*` that are related to JDK. But originally https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/commit/2d3dc92dda36f59d0f68fdc6d7595b0bf3aca99e this class was intended to catch `com.sun.*` and `sun.*` was added later. So I don't think this is a bug

Comment: @BalusC, I don't find this position very constructive. Obviously SonarQube can't provide pre-made rules for each and every imlementation details classes there are in the whole Java world. They started with what someone felt was the most important at the time (i.e. `com.sun.*`) and then extended it with one more very important thing (i.e. `sun.*`). But SonarQube is customizable and open source so you can add your own custom rules relevant to your project or even try to push them into the main repository.